# preg_match numberstring with separator PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a database column that contains the following type of data:

```
123/456 Big street road
789/123/112 Yellow road
23/23/2-44 Little brick street 221
1/2 Ocean view 4
```

I want to extract just the numbers separated by front slash. Like so:

```
123/456
789/123/112
23/23/2
1/2
```

For this I deviced the following pattern:

```
<?php
    preg_match("/[0-9]{1,4}\/[0-9]{1,4}|\/([0-9]{1,4})/", $data, $result);
?>
```

Needless to say... I'm not all there yet ;)

Comment: Splitting house numbers from streets is the bane of my life; any pattern matching that works in the Netherlands won't work in the UK for instance ... and absolutely nothing works in Ireland ... and that's before you factor in people entering data in unexpected ways. Honestly, if you can, use an address formatting service like Experian Data Quality or Postcode Anywhere.

Comment: You can also use like below :
 $subject="123/456 Big street road";
  $arr=explode(" ", $subject);
echo"<pre>"; print_r($arr);
Output: Array
(
    [0] => 123/456
    [1] => Big
    [2] => street
    [3] => road
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is what you're trying to match:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{1,4}(?:\/[0-9]{1,4})+/', $data, $result);
```

using a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:\/[0-9]{1,4})+` to repeat any number of slash and digits.

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL1sM0/1)</kbd>

---

And if you want to limit the ammount of numbers between 2 and 3, you can change the `+` to:

```
/[0-9]{1,4}(?:\/[0-9]{1,4}){1,2}/
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/\d{1,4}(?:\/\d{1,4})+/g', $data, $result);
```

Thing is:

1. preg_match_all() shows you all matches instead of first one
2. /g modifier states that matches will be searched through all of the text

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same format, you can explode it instead:

```
$row = '123/456 Big street road'; 
list($numbersWithSlashes) = explode(" ", $row);

var_dump($numbersWithSlashes);
```

As my teacher always said:

> Lazy programmers are good programmers. Do the same while making it easier.

Tho, skip my answer if it **has** te be regex or the format is not guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy/Easy solution -

Is it guaranteed that there will always be a space between the data and you want and the remaining? (you have control over it and that's how you always store data)

In that case simply split by a space and get the first item on the array.

```
$string  = "123/456 Big street road";
$strArray = explode(" ", $string);
echo $strArray[0]; //you may also check that this value does have "/"
```

I'm pretty sure the regex gurus will provide a better answer :). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/^([^\/]+\/\S+)/g', $data, $result)
```